# Accessing dataset schema + data from another class

Tags: c#

How can one access dataset schema + data between two classes in the same namespace? Please find below partial code:

```
namespace X
{
 //Class A
 public partial class form1
 { 
   datacolumn dtcHDR;
   datarow dtrHDR;
 public void button1_click(object sender, Event arg)
    {
     //Two datatable in dataset ds
     //Fetch data from sql view into dataset datatables (Header and Line)
     //Relationship between Header and Line tables in ds
    }
  }
}

 //Class B
 public CreateJE
 {
  foreach (DataRow dtrHDR in ds.Tables["Header"].Rows)
  // How can I access dtrHDR for ds in Class A?
  // Code
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A
{
   public void OnButtonClick(object sender, Event arg)
   {
      DataSet dataSet = ....

      B je = new B();      
      js.ProcessData(dataSet);
   }
}

class B
{
   public void ProcessData(DataSet dataSet)
   {
      foreach (DataRow dtrHDR in dataSet.Tables["Header"].Rows)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which context u are working, anyways u can:
Create a method/property in class A that return the needed data (to be called from class B)